# How to add a column header to the dynamic table

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I am creating a dynamic table to display the results from the database. I tried for ages but could not get it working. How can I add 2 header columns to this table?

```
private void BuildTable() {

        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();

        int rows = c.getCount();
        int cols = c.getColumnCount();

        c.moveToFirst();

        // outer for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                //tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                tv.setText(c.getString(j));

                row.addView(tv);

            }

            c.moveToNext();

            table_layout.addView(row);

        }
        sqlcon.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create TextView before the outer loop and create TableRow instance lets name it [ myrow ] then call : `myrow.addView(mytextview);`